# Database Replication Play .1.2.4

Tags: postgresql, playframework

I want to create a database replication, like a Master/Slave Databases for my play 1.2.4 framework app. I'm using PostgreSQL. Any guidance in this regard would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You could use the native replication from PostgreSQL (available as of version 9.0), works fine. [repmgr](http://www.repmgr.org) makes things easier to setup and maintain, also for automatic failover.

PostgreSQL supports asynchronous replication (as of 9.0) and synchronous replication ([as of 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION)).

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention Play 1.2, you may be using the default in-memory H2 database that comes with it and want to replicate data to PostgreSQL.  In any case, take a look at [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org) an open-source database replication engine that supports most databases, including H2 and PostgreSQL.  It supports master/slave and also multi-master with conflict management.  It is asynchronous replication that can work across a WAN, so it won't slow down your application if the network is slow or intermittent.  Since it supports replication between different database systems, you can change your platform in the future if needed.